# UITableView rows load asynchronously

Tags: uitableview, insert, rows

On launch of app, 
i want to show 10 rows, 
at the bottom "Load 15 more",
on click on "Load 15 more" the next 15 rows should add to the bottom of the table
and again show "Load 15 more", until no rows found.
note: I am using php to load table data as an xml feed.
If anyone has any tutorial/sample code pl send me the link

Comment: Mohan if you had solve this prob so plz share me the solution of this i'm new to iphone development and i have to implement this solution so kindly share the code with me...

Thanks In Advanced

Answer (score 5):

This could be helpful: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html

Answer (score 5):

I wrote something that might be useful to you : https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator

It encapsulates pagination, and works with pretty much any webservice. It also features a UITableView with automatic fetching of next results as you scroll down.

Comment: Very Very useful :) you saved may day @nmondollot

Comment: could you please help in using your code with another json webservice other than flicker?

Comment: what webservice do you want to use?

Comment: @hafedh I think it is the same, not master what service you useed.