# How to create button in the cell of the table view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a table view, the data for the table view is been added in the array. The array is having 5 data. I wanted to create a cell after the fifth row and create a button in that cell.
(Like load more options in the app stores applications list)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Load More" in UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410257/load-more-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if(indexpath.row == 5) {
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake( 0 , 0, 50, 20 );
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePostMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// add some other button properties here 
[cell.contentView addSubView:button];
[button release]; 
}
```

also you should return 6 in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake( 0 , 0, 50, 20 );
// add some other button properties here 
cell.accessoryView = button;
[button release];
```

Comment: This will create button at the end of the each cell in the table view. I wanted to add the button at the bottom of the table view

Comment: You can add this property to ( 5 * (n+1) )th row. When user taps on that it does the action( like loading five more ) and then you can increase n by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
        UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 3, 26, 36)];
        deleteButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;     
        UIImage *newImage12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete1.png"];
        deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [deleteButton setBackgroundImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePostMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:deleteButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //for inserting submit button at the end of the section
    UIView *footerView=nil;
    if(section == 4)
    {
    footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIButton *btnSubmit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnSubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(570, 22, 120, 50)];
    [btnSubmit setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnSubmit.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];
    [btnSubmit setTitleColor:[UIColor lightTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *btnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark-green.png"];//setting image of button
    [btnSubmit setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [footerView addSubview:btnSubmit];
    }
    return footerView;    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context? What is it that this code does exactly?