# issues with UITableView performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am pulling data from a web service in order to populate my UITableView rows. It loads perfectly fine, however it takes around 4 seconds in order to load the whole data. Is there a way in that I can increase the time to load? Probably by caching it? Or any tips and tricks on what people usually do to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to increase the loading time? And caching will only decrease it.

Comment: I think I meant to say asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display old data and asynchronously fetch using threads the new data and then reload the UITableView

Comment: I like the asynchronous idea you have, any example on how to do this via UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Caching depends on what you're loading. If you're loading, say, Twitter feeds, you should cache the user avatar pictures because you know you'll be fetching them over and over again. If you're writing something like a retail app, you might show items that are on sale. If the items change every Sunday, then cache them the first time you fetch them and don't fetch them again until Sunday. That sort of thing.

Beyond that, there's not much you can do to make the internet faster. If you have control over the web service, you can make the data sent back as concise and simple as possible. You'd be surprised how many milliseconds you can burn parsing complicated XML.

If it makes sense for your app, you can show old data. For a twitter client, it's better to just save the data you've already fetched, show it immediately, and load the new stuff in the background.

If you can't do any of that, then pretty much all you can do is put up a "Loading..." overlay of some sort so that the app doesn't just look frozen and live with the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Three20 TTTableViewController, nice tutorial can be found here:
[Three20](http://www.raywenderlich.com/656/introduction-to-three20)

Moreover, you can add "Load more results" button, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551035/uitableview-rows-load-asynchronously)

Comment: What's the advantage of Three20 TableViewController compared to UITableView?

Comment: it handles all the asynchronous loading and the networking for u.